# images not stacking for fading slider

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to get my images within my header-image-border to stack so I can fade away and cycle through them, as currently the fade out, changing attr, and fading in, just doesn't cut it, even with pre-loading images, it still seems to have to load the image random, even if it's been displayed in the cycle already.

http://jordan.rave5.com/tmptemp/

**CSS**

```
            #header-image-border {
                z-index: 400;
                height: 453px;
                width: 100%;
                min-width: 1024px;
                max-height: 453px;
                transition: width 2s;
                -webkit-transition: width 2s;
                padding-bottom: 4px;
                background-image: url(images/border.png);
                background-repeat: repeat-x;
                background-position: bottom;
            }

            #header-image-border img {
                width: 100%;
                height: 453px;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
            }
```

**HTML**

```
                    <div id="header-image-border">
                        <img class="header-img" id="hi1" src="slides/head1.jpg" alt="The Tiger Spot" />
                        <img class="header-img" id="hi2" src="slides/head2.jpg" alt="The Tiger Spot" />
                        <img class="header-img" id="hi3" src="slides/head3.jpg" alt="The Tiger Spot" />
                        <img class="header-img" id="hi4" src="slides/head4.jpg" alt="The Tiger Spot" />
                        <div class="image-grad">
                            <div id="drop-ucp-container">
                                <div id="drop-ucp"><input class="search" type="text" size="25" value="Search" /> <input class="submit" type="button" value="Search" /></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is you forgot to position the items:

```
#header-image-border {
    position: relative;
    ...
}

#header-image-border img {
    position: absolute;
    ...
}
```

Now they should be on top of each other.

Comment: Thank you!... Now why the heck is it causing all the jquery to mess up and slide up and down things then hide them. o.o weeeird.